# Hangfire job shows error on console but gets triggered manually

Tags: c#, hangfire

I created and registered a job which runs just fine when triggered manually.
Sometimes when it's supposed to trigger at its scheduled time, it shows an error on the console and doesn't run.

The error looks like this:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Recurring job can't be scheduled, see inner exception for details.
 ---> Hangfire.Common.JobLoadException: Could not load the job. See inner exception for the details.
 ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not resolve assembly 'Jobs.MyCustomJob'.
   at System.TypeNameParser.ResolveAssembly(String asmName, Func`2 assemblyResolver, Boolean throwOnError, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.TypeNameParser.ConstructType(Func`2 assemblyResolver, Func`4 typeResolver, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.TypeNameParser.GetType(String typeName, Func`2 assemblyResolver, Func`4 typeResolver, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Type.GetType(String typeName, Func`2 assemblyResolver, Func`4 typeResolver, Boolean throwOnError)
   at Hangfire.Common.TypeHelper.DefaultTypeResolver(String typeName)
   at Hangfire.Storage.InvocationData.DeserializeJob()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Hangfire.Storage.InvocationData.DeserializeJob()
   at Hangfire.RecurringJobEntity..ctor(String recurringJobId, IDictionary`2 recurringJob, ITimeZoneResolver timeZoneResolver, DateTime now)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Hangfire.Server.RecurringJobScheduler.ScheduleRecurringJob(BackgroundProcessContext context, IStorageConnection connection, String recurringJobId, RecurringJobEntity recurringJob, DateTime now)
```

And hangfire console looks like this:

[image: Hangfire Console with the error button instead of Next execution]

But I'm still able to manually trigger the job and it runs without any issue (it's actually running as I write this, having been triggered manually).

I have checked the references in the Console Webapp and everything looks fine, all other 100+ jobs are fine and this one even this faulty job seems to run on schedule sometimes.

Massive thanks in advance for any ideas of what could that be. If I manage to find the answer I'll update it for future reference.

Comment: It seems it can't find assembly `Jobs.MyJobs` .. I'd check if that assembly is in the build/publish folder first (even though you mentioned it works sometimes).. can you also share the code to schedule the job?

Comment: I see that you have two hangfore servers. It is possible that the assemblies are present on one and not the other. Can you check what server the job successfully runs on ?

Comment: @BrunoFarias, the assembly is in the build folder. I can start the job manually 100% of the time and it fails to start automatically also 100% of the time.
Registration is done with a simple 
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<MyJob>(Constants.MyJob, job => job.Run(null), "*/5 * * * *");

Comment: @Jawad the two servers each process different queues, so it's not something to worry about.